# Efficiently finding range from ordered list of ranges with preprocessing

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, data-structures

Say we have a list of ranges like so:

`ranges = [(0, 100), (101, 200), (201, 300)]`

The ranges will always be ordered, never overlap, and perfectly align.

We want to optimise the complexity of `O(p + kl)`, where `p` is the preprocessing time, `k` represents the number of lookups of a range and `l` represents an individual lookup time.

E.g. With the above range list and preprocessing, how can we quickly map the value of `150` to index `1` or the tuple `(101, 200)` as it lies within that range.

My initial idea was to perform a binary search to find the range, as the list is ordered resulting in constant preprocessing time (`p = 1`), and a lookup time `l` of `O(log m)`, where `m` is the number of ranges. Overall complexity `O(k (log m))`.

Another idea was to store a massive array of the smallest number to the largest number, and map it to the range index. So for the above example, have a map for all values from `0` to `300` and map them to their respective index. This would result in `O(n)` preprocessing time where `n` is the total number of values in the entire range list , but constant lookup time (`l = O(1)`). Overall complexity of `O(n + k)`.

Option 2 obviously also uses heaps of extra space.

**I was just wondering if there are any other approaches to solve this problem?**

Comment: I don't understand the question.  It sounds like you want a data structure to do something, but what operations do you want the data structure to support?  Please specify the problem more clearly.

Comment: We have numbers from 0 to n. This 0 to n is split into "ranges". E.g. if n = 100, the ranges could be [(0, 10), (11, 50), (51, 100)]. The problem is then given a number x such that x >= 0 and x <= n, is there an efficient way to lookup x's range. E.g. Using the above example of ranges, if x is 25, can we find (11, 50) in constant time. The catch is we are allowed to preprocess, and we are trying to optimse just the lookup time.

Comment: Please don't add information in the comments.  Instead, [edit] the question so it has all necessary information and reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  Thank you!

Comment: @searly2710 are gaps possible? For example for $[(1,10),(21,30),(31,40)]$, range $(11,20)$ is missing

Comment: (@Russel: gaps don't fit `ranges[…]perfectly align` & `numbers from 0 to n[…] is split into "ranges"`.)

Comment: If by perfectly aligned, it means the ranges have same size (although it appears that the first range is always the odd one out based on the examples) and there is no gap, then isn't it possible to simply compute in $O(1)$ the range where an integer will fall? Or am i missing something

Comment: (@Russel I read *perfectly align* as *no overlaps, no gaps* (seeing a bit of redundancy in the question's wording). Regarding size, see [searly2710's comment](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/150538/efficiently-finding-range-from-ordered-list-of-ranges-with-preprocessing#comment316451_150538) (that should have been an edit).)